# Show/Hide Div with the result of controller method in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

What i have.
(1) ASP.Net MVC application.
(2) In View I have one Link (ActionLink) 
    and 
(3) One Div with textbox.

I want to show OR hide the textbox on the click of ActionLink 
But, the ActionLink calls the controller method called 'SendData'.
This method returns Boolean value (True/False) accordingly i will show the Div.
Can anyone tell me how do i do this in ASP.Net MVC

Answer (score 0):

You Can Make use of Jquery Ajax to achieve this

Step 1) On click of the action link make a ajax call to the Action Method

Step 2) As mentioned a boolean value is returned from the Action Method

Step 3) In the done or success funtion of Ajax , show or hide the respective div .

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax to make the call, get the boolean response from your SendData action method and hide or show the div accordingly.

Assuming you have jQuery loaded to your page, Include this code to your page.

```
@Html.ActionLink("SendData","SendData",null,new {@id="myLink"})
<input type="text" id="myTextBox" />

@section Scripts
{
 <script>
 $(function(){

   $("#myLink").click(function(e){

      e.preventDefault();
      $.get($(this).attr("href"),function(res){
         if(res==="True")
         {
          $("#myTextBox").show();
         }
         else
         {
           $("#myTextBox").hide();
         }
      });

   });

 });
 </script>
}
```

The above code listens to the `click` event on the link (*with id myLink*) and make an ajax call to your SendData action method and do appropriate things based on the response.

Comment: how do we pass the values in the call ? 
From jquery to Controller method (as parameter).
Can you please post the code of controller as well.
Thanks in Advance !

Comment: What parameter you want to pass ? A simple value? Pass as the query string. A complex object ? Change the get call to post call with the data.